# Запуск бота Telegram на Heroku на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask, heroku, gunicorn

Написал тестового бота Телеграм на Python с использование фреймворка Flask. Все работает нормально. Но хочу изменить запуск, запускать с помощью Gunicorn. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что изменить в проекте? Пустой файл **init**.py сделал....
Содержимое файла Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
pytelegrambotapi = "*"
flask = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Содержимое файла Procfile:

```
web: python app.py --log-file -
```

Cодержимое файла app.py:

```
import telebot
import os
from flask import Flask, request

bot = telebot.TeleBot('bla-bla-bla')

server = Flask(__name__)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

@server.route("/bot", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200

@server.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url="https://bla-bla-bla/bot")
    return "!", 200

server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
server = Flask(__name__)
```

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Укажите в Procfile использование gunicorn

```
web: gunicron my_app:app
```